# How to separate 2 output arrays of sklearn kneighbors() Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am a beginner in Python and I use NearestNeighbors in sklearn and the output is:

```
print(neigh.kneighbors([[0.00015217, 0.00050968, 0.00044049, 0.00014538, 
0.00077339, 0.0020284 , 0.00047572]]))
```

And the output is:

```
(array([[1.01980586e-08, 7.73354596e-05, 7.73354596e-05, 1.20134585e-04,
1.39792434e-04, 1.48002389e-04, 1.98794609e-04, 4.63512739e-04,
    5.31436554e-04, 5.36960418e-04, 5.72679303e-04, 6.28187320e-04,
    6.67923141e-04, 7.51928163e-04, 8.97313642e-04, 1.00023442e-03,
    1.06114362e-03, 1.11943158e-03, 1.12626043e-03, 1.20185118e-03,
    1.51073901e-03, 1.71592746e-03, 1.73362257e-03]]),array([[ 0, 16, 15, 
    19,1, 23,  5,  8, 20,  9,6, 10, 17,  3, 21, 22,14,  2, 13,  7, 11, 12, 
    18]],dtype=int64))
```

I would like to import these data to csv because I need both the arrays in csv. how can I separate these arrays?

Comment: Hi! Please write down the code and output instead of using an image. This will enable users to reproduce the error way faster :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hh = neigh.kneighbors([[0.00015217, 0.00050968, 0.00044049, 0.00014538, 
0.00077339, 0.0020284 , 0.00047572]])
first_array = hh[0]
second_array = hh[1]
```